# Getting an error when trying to use imagePickerController Delegate function below:

Tags: ios, xcode7-beta4

When trying to use the following function

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController,didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String: AnyObject]?) {
    let selectedImage:UIImage = (editingInfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]) as! UIImage
    displayImage.image = selectedImage
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

getting error:
"Cannot subscript a value of type '[String:AnyObject]? with an index of type 'String'

on the second line where it I write the let selected Image

This has worked fine with Xcode 6.3 & 6.4 but now with new Xcode 7 beta 4 does not work and throws an error.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Try dismissing controller before setting image to imageView.
replace your methods as:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
 self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
let selectedImage:UIImage = (editingInfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]) as! UIImage
displayImage.image = selectedImage

}
```

Comment: Why would dismiss view controller help? No it still generates an Error.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out the answer looking in the documentation of imagePickerController. the method I had to use is didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo instead and as follows:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    let selectedImage:UIImage = (info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]) as! UIImage
    displayImage.image = selectedImage
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: thats what i suggested. see closely my answer